# FileReader.onload, onloadend, addEventListener not work on Ionic Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, filereader

After 4 days of searching, I can't find any solution for my application :(.

I'm stuck with FileReader can't firing onload event, so I can't get result.

I have try different way to get it but no once work.

So hope you guy can help me slove this problem... :(

this is code (run in Android, just send url toDataURL):

```
function toDataUrl(url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onloadend = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
      console.log("event: ", event.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
}
```

Many thanks :D

Comment: Maybe you need to use the "real" filereader and not the cordova one: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/505#issuecomment-503316333